# Is it safe to run SCRIPT FLUSH on Redis cluster?

Tags: redis

Recently, I started to have some trouble with one of me Redis cluster. `used_memroy` and `used_memory_rss` increasing constantly.

According to some Googling, I found following discussion:
https://github.com/antirez/redis/issues/4570

Now I am wandering if it is safe to run `SCRIPT FLUSH` command on my production Redis cluster?

Answer (score 1):

Yes - you can run the `SCRIPT FLUSH` command safely in a production cluster. The only potential side effect is blocking the server while it executes. Note, however, that you'll want to call it in each of your nodes.